# False positives during asynchronous TCP scanning through the Socks5 Proxy relay

Tags: go, tcp, proxy

I am learning golang and wanted to build a TCP port scanner with SOCKS5 proxies as a relay for mass scanning.

Although all of the S5 proxies are being checked for every target scan, sometimes there are some False positives - and I cannot find the reason why.

Preparing proxyDialer:

```
func create_socks5_tcp_dialer(socks5_addr string) proxy.Dialer {
    //socks5_dialer_tcp, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", socks5_addr, nil, proxy.Direct)
    socks5_dialer_tcp, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", socks5_addr, nil, &net.Dialer{Timeout: 5 * time.Second, KeepAlive: 5 * time.Second})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to proxy:", err)
    }
    return socks5_dialer_tcp
}
```

Validating socks5 address:

```
func socks5_validator(socks5_addr, vps_opened, vps_closed string) (bool, string) {
    /*  Check if SOCKS5 proxy is valid.
        1. Connect to the open port on the server under my control using proxy.
        2. Connect to the closed port on the server under my control using proxy.
            - If both checks are true then, SOCKS5 proxy is considered as valid.
            - If one of the check is false, SOCKS5 proxy is considered as invalid.
        3. Returns true/false and s5_addr.
    */
    // Create SOCKS5 dialer
    socks5_dialer_tcp := create_socks5_tcp_dialer(socks5_addr)
    // Make connection using SOCKS5 proxy to the opened port on the vps.
    conn_1, err := socks5_dialer_tcp.Dial("tcp", vps_opened)
    // If it was successful and not generate any error then check1 is passed.
    if err == nil {
        //fmt.Println("CHECK 1: PASSED")
        conn_1.Close()
        // If error was generated then check is not passed and do not make check2.
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("CHECK 1: NOT PASSED")
        return false, socks5_addr
    }
    // Make connection using SOCKS5 proxy to the closed port on the vps.
    conn_2, err := socks5_dialer_tcp.Dial("tcp", vps_closed)
    // If it was unsuccessful and error was generated then check2 is passed.
    if err != nil {
        //fmt.Println("CHECK 2: PASSED")
        // If both checks were passed then return false.
        return true, socks5_addr
        // If error was not generated then check2 is not passed.
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("CHECK 2: NOT PASSED")
        conn_2.Close()
        return false, socks5_addr
    }
}
```

Port scanning

```
s5_dialer_tcp := create_socks5_tcp_dialer(socks5_addr)
            // Scan target using s5
            conn, err := s5_dialer_tcp.Dial("tcp", target)
            if err != nil {
                //open
            } else {
                //closed
            }
```

My question is:
Do I correctly scan TCP services through the SOCKS5 proxy and do I validate this proxy properly?

Link to the full code:
https://github.com/Karmaz95/crimson_prober

Comment: When I conduct final scanning against the target using checked (valid) Socks5 proxy relay for example:
Target => 10.10.10.10:1234
Port 1234 is closed and the scanner shows that it is opened.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that these are actual false positives. Instead you are having the wrong assumptions of how these proxies will work: You  assume that if the *single* check for a *specific* port open (connect success) and a *specific* port closed (connect failure) on a *specific* server at a *specific* time succeeds, then the proxy can be used to *reliably* check *many* *arbitrary* ports on *arbitrary* servers at *arbitrary* times.

This assumption is likely not valid, especially given that you seem to use proxies which are outside of your control.

A common behavior of such proxies is that they provide only restricted access, i.e. common ports like HTTP and HTTPS will work while other ports will be blocked. Proxies might also employ rate limiting, so they will simply deny access through the proxy after a while. And free proxies available in some lists often cease to work after a while.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am not under control over the S5 proxies that I am using, but I do control my VPS and that is why I checked twice for opened and closed ports. For opened one, I chose the not standard port like 7231 and for the closed one, I chose 80/443/22 one of the known ports. This should give me reliable information on whether the S5 proxy is valid or not.

If you have a different opinion, then how should I validate these addresses before using them to be 100% sure of the result.

Comment: "Proxies might also employ rate limiting, so they will simply deny access through the proxy after a while." - I know that, that is why I am checking every proxy that I am using, just before TCP connect scan every time.

Comment: @KarolMazurek: This assumes that the rate limit denies access only during your check, but not during scanning after your successful check.

Comment: I understand, however, this target scan occurs almost immediately after checking the S5, so I guess that's not the problem. 
Moreover, if it was a rate limit, I probably couldn't have been able to connect to s5 and conduct the target scan using this S5 dialer. So my question is still open, what besides the rate limit could go wrong here?

Comment: @KarolMazurek: The main thing I pointed out was not the rate limiting but the restriction which ports are made accessible by the proxy. Also, the idea of rate limiting is to not allow too much connections. This usually means that initial connections work (i.e. your check of the proxy) and after a while it will stop working (i.e. during scanning).